# Change Spring @Length annotation with JMX?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jmx, spring-jmx

I'm using a @Length(min=constant) annotation, which takes values for constant that must be a constant expression like a final value. I'd like to change that value using JMX, but can't set min to some variable that isn't final. How can I change the JMX value if it's not final?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you cannot change the parameters to the Validator annotations at runtime. They must be constant values at the time of compilation.